Can a component be created that allows the specific flow name that a subflow runs to be taken from a flow variable?
When you add the standard Subflow component to a flow in the Flow Builder, the flow it will run has to be chosen immediately. I have a case where multiple subflows (that work in the same context) and have arbitrary names would best be selected at runtime from a variable in the flow.
Is creating a custom screen flow component likely to be possible that allows this? Or is there some other solution?

I think this may be helpful for your goal: https://unofficialsf.com/dynamic-launching-of-screen-flows/
This would allow you to run subflows dynamically, whether it's a screen flow or autolaunched flow. I've used this in the past and it's worked very well.

Thanks SFDC_Sebastian - very helpful. In my case I want to show a series of screen flow components in the master flow, then pass a record Id to the subflow starting it so it can itself present more screens, then return to the master flow immediately after where the subflow was started from. Think that would require a lot of messy inout/output work? Your thoughts?
